How to avoid circular imports with PySide6
Original file, mre.py
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import (Qt, QSize, QPoint, QRect,
                            QEvent, QObject,
                            Signal, SignalInstance, Slot,
                            )

from PySide6.QtGui import (QResizeEvent, QMoveEvent,
                           QFocusEvent, )

from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel,
                               QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, 
                               QMainWindow, QApplication,
                               QSizePolicy, QLayout, QLayoutItem
                               )

class CustomEventFilter(QObject):
    """Installs eventFilter obj on a widget.

    Args:
        widget: QWidget instance
    """
    def __init__(self, widget: QWidget):
        # if you don't pass widget to be a parent of this evFilter,
        # then the event filter will most likely be destroyed.
        super().__init__(widget)   
        
        # set protected variable
        self._widget = widget
        
        # Install this filterObj instance on the given widget
        self.widget.installEventFilter(self)

    # Encapsulation stuff
    @property
    def widget(self):
        return self._widget    

    def eventFilter(self, obj: QWidget, event: QEvent):
        match (event.type()):
            case _:
                # For all events other than move and resize, handle according to QObject built-in eventFilter().
                return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

class MeatballEventFilter(CustomEventFilter):
    def __init__(self, widget, sig: Signal = None):
        super().__init__(widget)
        self._sig = sig

    @property
    def widget(self) -> QWidget:
        return self._widget
    
    @property
    def sig(self) -> SignalInstance:
        return self._sig
    
    def eventFilter(self, obj: QWidget, event: QEvent):
        match (event.type()):
            case QEvent.FocusOut:
                # print("Lost focus!\nReason: {}".format(event.reason()))
                # if event.reason() == Qt.FocusReason.ActiveWindowFocusReason:
                #     return True

                # self.sig.emit(self.widget)
                return True
            case QEvent.FocusIn:
                # print("Gained focus!")
                return True
            case _:
                return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

class WindowEventFilter(CustomEventFilter):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__(widget)

    @property
    def widget(self):
        return super().widget
    
    def eventFilter(self, obj: QWidget, event:QEvent):
        match (event.type()):
            case QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                #TODO
                print("mouse window!")
                sub: SubBox = obj.findChild(SubBox)

                evFilter: SubBoxEventFilter = sub.findChild(SubBoxEventFilter)
                return evFilter.eventFilter(sub, event)

                # return sub.eventFilter(sub, event)  # this doesn't work.
            case _:
                return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

class SubBoxEventFilter(CustomEventFilter): 
    """blah blah blah
    """
    def __init__(self, widget: QWidget):
        super().__init__(widget)

    @property
    def widget(self):
        return super().widget

    def eventFilter(self, obj: QObject, event:QEvent):
        # print(type(obj))
        match (event.type()):
            case QEvent.Resize:   # TODO
                # Won't matter for final product(I think?) but for test purposes will be implemented here
                
                return True
            
            case QEvent.Move:
                # Check meatball
                print("Sub moving meatball!")
                if obj.findChild(TestSongMeatball):
                    meatball: TestSongMeatball = obj.findChild(TestSongMeatball)
                    meatball.findPos()
                    return True
                
                # Return True to notify app that moving took place.
                return True
            
            case _:
                # For all events other than move and resize, handle according to QObject built-in eventFilter().
                return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


class TestSong(QWidget):

    # Create signals to relay info about meatball
    meatballCreated = Signal(QWidget, name="meatballCreated")
    meatballDestroyed = Signal(QWidget, name="meatballDestroyed")

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")

        # Init layout on widget
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        # Crate widgets
        label = QLabel("Label")
        meatball = TestSongButton("Meatball button")

        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(meatball)

        # connect clicked signal to relay into a meatballCreate signal, passing this widget
        # as a param
        meatball.clicked.connect(
            lambda checked: self.meatballCreated.emit(self))  
    
class TestSongButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__(text)

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: purple")
    
class TestSongMeatball(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, songWidget: TestSong, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Set reference to song widget
        self._songWidget = songWidget

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")

        # Create sizePolicy obj, init with horizontal and vertical preferences
        policy = QSizePolicy()
        policy.setHorizontalPolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
        policy.setVerticalPolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)

        # Set policy, min and max size of the widget.
        self.setSizePolicy(policy)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(70, 50))
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(160, 80))

        fPolicy = Qt.FocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setFocusPolicy(fPolicy)

        # Assign layout to widget
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        # Add demo label for clarity
        text = QLabel("Meatball Menu")
        layout.addWidget(text)

    @property
    def songWidget(self):
        return self._songWidget

    def findPos(self):
        p = self.parent()
        # First check that there is a song meatball created as a child of monitorObj (_widget)
        if p.findChild(TestSongMeatball):
            # find song item and store its position
            item_pos = self.songWidget.pos()

            # Type hint for Python intellisense purposes
            # find button within song item and store its position
            button: TestSongButton = self.songWidget.findChild(TestSongButton)
            button_pos = button.pos()

            # since item sits inside SubBox, the meatball will have the same geometry starting point (I think?)
            # So to find the button we need to add them
            x,y = item_pos.x(), item_pos.y()
            nx,ny, = button_pos.x(), button_pos.y()

            # Add co-ordinates to get button's top left corner
            meatball_pos = QPoint(x+nx,y+ny)
            
            # Move to new position, then allow QT to find correct size, using SizePolicy.
            self.move(meatball_pos)
            self.adjustSize()

        return

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(80,60)

class SubBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")

        # Create and apply layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self) 

    @Slot()
    def addWid(self, item: TestSong):
        if self.findChild(TestSongMeatball):
            print("Meatball already present.")
            return
        
        # Create meatball widget
        meatball = TestSongMeatball(item, self)
        evFilter = MeatballEventFilter(meatball, item.meatballDestroyed)

        meatball.findPos()
        meatball.show()  # show meatball
        meatball.setFocus()

        return

    @Slot()
    def remWid(self, meatball: TestSongMeatball):
        meatball.deleteLater()
        meatball = None

        return

class TestWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        window_widget = QWidget()
        window_layout = QVBoxLayout(window_widget)

        winFilter = WindowEventFilter(window_widget)

        fPolicy = Qt.FocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setFocusPolicy(fPolicy)

        #TODO: put this into a function
        # Give total layout a label
        window_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Window"))
        
        # Create sub-box
        sub = SubBox()

        # Install event filter to SubBox
        subFilter = SubBoxEventFilter(sub)

        test_widget = TestSong()

        sub.layout().addWidget(test_widget)
        
        window_layout.addWidget(sub)
        
        test_widget.meatballCreated.connect(
            lambda item: sub.addWid(item))
        
        test_widget.meatballDestroyed.connect(
            lambda meatball : sub.remWid(meatball))
        
        # set window as central
        self.setCentralWidget(window_widget)
        
def main():
    # Create app
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I am wondering the best way to split this code up. I have so far tried to move the CustomEventFilter, MeatballEventFilter, SubBoxEventFilter, WindowEventFilter classes into their own file, called EvFilter.py. Then importing SubBox, TestSongMeatball into EvFilter.py to allow QWidget.findChild() to find the widget in question.
This left me with two files, EvFilter.py and mre.py, the former containing all subclasses of CustomEventFilter and importing SubBox, TestSongMeatball to it; and the latter containing TestSong, TestSongButton, TestSongMeatball, SubBox, TestWindow and main(), then importing all subclasses of CustomEventFilter.
I can see how this would create a circular import clearly, and tried to remedy the issue with fixes I found online.
When trying to import the whole file and then access the individual classes, something like:
import mre

sub = obj.findChild(mre.SubBox)

The findChild() function would return None.
Clearly I need to restructure the program to avoid this flaw, but don't know the best way of doing so. That, or I need to find the child of a QWidget without using findChild().
EvFilter.py
from PySide6.QtCore import (QEvent, QObject,
                            Signal, SignalInstance, 
                            )

from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QWidget, )

from mre import (TestSongMeatball, SubBox, )

class CustomEventFilter(QObject):
    """Installs eventFilter obj on a widget.

    Args:
        widget: QWidget instance
    """
    def __init__(self, widget: QWidget):
        # if you don't pass widget to be a parent of this evFilter,
        # then the event filter will most likely be destroyed.
        super().__init__(widget)   
        
        # set protected variable
        self._widget = widget
        
        # Install this filterObj instance on the given widget
        self.widget.installEventFilter(self)

    # Encapsulation stuff
    @property
    def widget(self):
        return self._widget    

    def eventFilter(self, obj: QWidget, event: QEvent):
        match (event.type()):
            case _:
                # For all events other than move and resize, handle according to QObject built-in eventFilter().
                return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

class MeatballEventFilter(CustomEventFilter):
    def __init__(self, widget, sig: Signal = None):
        super().__init__(widget)
        self._sig = sig

    @property
    def widget(self) -> QWidget:
        return self._widget
    
    @property
    def sig(self) -> SignalInstance:
        return self._sig
    
    def eventFilter(self, obj: QWidget, event: QEvent):
        match (event.type()):
            case QEvent.FocusOut:
                # print("Lost focus!\nReason: {}".format(event.reason()))
                # if event.reason() == Qt.FocusReason.ActiveWindowFocusReason:
                #     return True

                # self.sig.emit(self.widget)
                return True
            case QEvent.FocusIn:
                # print("Gained focus!")
                return True
            case _:
                return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

class WindowEventFilter(CustomEventFilter):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__(widget)

    @property
    def widget(self):
        return super().widget
    
    def eventFilter(self, obj: QWidget, event:QEvent):
        match (event.type()):
            case QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                #TODO
                print("mouse window!")
                sub: SubBox = obj.findChild(SubBox)

                evFilter: SubBoxEventFilter = sub.findChild(SubBoxEventFilter)
                return evFilter.eventFilter(sub, event)

                # return sub.eventFilter(sub, event)  # this doesn't work.
            case _:
                return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

class SubBoxEventFilter(CustomEventFilter): 
    """blah blah blah
    """
    def __init__(self, widget: QWidget):
        super().__init__(widget)

    @property
    def widget(self):
        return super().widget

    # Actual eventFilter function. Obj will be the widget this filterObj is installed on,
    # Event is a subclass of QEvent and can be accessed through its enum: 
    # QEvent.Resize is similar to QResizeEvent
    def eventFilter(self, obj: QObject, event:QEvent):
        # print(type(obj))
        match (event.type()):
            case QEvent.Resize:   # TODO
                # Won't matter for final product(I think?) but for test purposes will be implemented here
                
                return True
            
            case QEvent.Move:
                # Check meatball
                print("Sub moving meatball!")
                if obj.findChild(TestSongMeatball):
                    meatball: TestSongMeatball = obj.findChild(TestSongMeatball)
                    meatball.findPos()
                    return True
                
                # Return True to notify app that moving took place.
                return True
            
            case _:
                # For all events other than move and resize, handle according to QObject built-in eventFilter().
                return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


mre.py, without event filters
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import (Qt, QSize, QPoint, QRect,
                            QEvent, QObject,
                            Signal, SignalInstance, Slot,
                            )

from PySide6.QtGui import (QResizeEvent, QMoveEvent,
                           QFocusEvent, )

from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel,
                               QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, 
                               QMainWindow, QApplication,
                               QSizePolicy, QLayout, QLayoutItem
                               )

import EvFilter

class TestSong(QWidget):

    # Create signals to relay info about meatball
    meatballCreated = Signal(QWidget, name="meatballCreated")
    meatballDestroyed = Signal(QWidget, name="meatballDestroyed")

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")

        # Init layout on widget
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        # Crate widgets
        label = QLabel("Label")
        meatball = TestSongButton("Meatball button")

        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(meatball)

        # connect clicked signal to relay into a meatballCreate signal, passing this widget
        # as a param
        meatball.clicked.connect(
            lambda checked: self.meatballCreated.emit(self))  
    
class TestSongButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__(text)

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: purple")
    
class TestSongMeatball(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, songWidget: TestSong, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Set reference to song widget
        self._songWidget = songWidget

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")

        # Create sizePolicy obj, init with horizontal and vertical preferences
        policy = QSizePolicy()
        policy.setHorizontalPolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
        policy.setVerticalPolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)

        # Set policy, min and max size of the widget.
        self.setSizePolicy(policy)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(70, 50))
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(160, 80))

        fPolicy = Qt.FocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setFocusPolicy(fPolicy)

        # Assign layout to widget
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        # Add demo label for clarity
        text = QLabel("Meatball Menu")
        layout.addWidget(text)

    @property
    def songWidget(self):
        return self._songWidget

    def findPos(self):
        p = self.parent()
        # First check that there is a song meatball created as a child of monitorObj (_widget)
        if p.findChild(TestSongMeatball):
            # find song item and store its position
            item_pos = self.songWidget.pos()

            # Type hint for Python intellisense purposes
            # find button within song item and store its position
            button: TestSongButton = self.songWidget.findChild(TestSongButton)
            button_pos = button.pos()

            # since item sits inside SubBox, the meatball will have the same geometry starting point (I think?)
            # So to find the button we need to add them
            x,y = item_pos.x(), item_pos.y()
            nx,ny, = button_pos.x(), button_pos.y()

            # Add co-ordinates to get button's top left corner
            meatball_pos = QPoint(x+nx,y+ny)
            
            # Move to new position, then allow QT to find correct size, using SizePolicy.
            self.move(meatball_pos)
            self.adjustSize()

        return

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(80,60)

class SubBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")

        # Create and apply layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self) 

    @Slot()
    def addWid(self, item: TestSong):
        if self.findChild(TestSongMeatball):
            print("Meatball already present.")
            return
        
        # Create meatball widget
        meatball = TestSongMeatball(item, self)
        evFilter = EvFilter.MeatballEventFilter(meatball, item.meatballDestroyed)

        meatball.findPos()
        meatball.show()  # show meatball
        meatball.setFocus()

        return

    @Slot()
    def remWid(self, meatball: TestSongMeatball):
        meatball.deleteLater()
        meatball = None

        return

class TestWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        window_widget = QWidget()
        window_layout = QVBoxLayout(window_widget)

        winFilter = EvFilter.WindowEventFilter(window_widget)

        fPolicy = Qt.FocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setFocusPolicy(fPolicy)

        #TODO: put this into a function
        # Give total layout a label
        window_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Window"))
        
        # Create sub-box
        sub = SubBox()

        # Install event filter to SubBox
        subFilter = EvFilter.SubBoxEventFilter(sub)

        test_widget = TestSong()

        sub.layout().addWidget(test_widget)
        
        window_layout.addWidget(sub)
        
        test_widget.meatballCreated.connect(
            lambda item: sub.addWid(item))
        
        test_widget.meatballDestroyed.connect(
            lambda meatball : sub.remWid(meatball))
        
        # set window as central
        self.setCentralWidget(window_widget)
        
def main():
    # Create app
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


The solution is quite simple: avoid the cause of circular imports to begin with. All the classes of mre that may also be used in other modules should be moved into another file, so that they can be separately and independently imported from mre and EvFilter.

So would that mean having a file for each class? And then leave EvFilter as is, or should I have the baseclass CustomEventFilter be its own file, import into the separate files i.e. TestSongMeatball.py and have the subclasses related to the objects they are installed upon be part of the same file?

I never said that each class should have a separate file. Logic separation should follow the usage and requirements of each object, possibly grouping classes based on their type, purpose or inheritance. For instance, put widgets in a widgets.py file and event filters in an eventFilters.py file, then just import what you actually need in the main script.

I was unable to separate widgets and eventFilters into two files, with a main.py containing only main(). I instead put associated filters with their install targets (MeatballEventFilter in same file as TestSongMeatball.

Those event-filter classes don't serve any useful purpose, since they're only used by one widget, which is itself already a subclass. Thus, there's no code re-use whatsoever, and there's no meaningful separation of concerns. You should instead reimplement the relevant built-in event-handlers (such as mouseReleaseEvent) within the widget subclasses themselves. This will make the code more efficient and much easier to maintain. Monitoring events via other objects should be reserved for cases where you cannot (or would prefer not to) subclass the target object.

Well. This would have been a great response to my post that initially led me to using the eventFilter. At least I now know to implement my own.
Could you link to/explain your last sentence, about not wanting to subclass the target object?

One very common use-case occurs with a generated ui from Qt Designer, where the child widgets can only be accessed after they've already been created. There are ways around this (such as widget promotion), but that's usually only worth doing where more extensive customisation is needed. More commonly, a main window (or dialog) inherits/creates the ui and reimplements eventFilter so that child widgets from the ui can be tweaked by monitoring their events.

The event-filter system isn't intended for general event-handling. It simply provides a way for one widget to intercept selected events of another widget. There's very rarely any need to create dedicated monitoring objects for this purpose, since all widget classes inherit QObject. A top-level window/dialog is often better placed for this, since it should normally have direct access to the target widget (by keeping an explicit reference to it as an attribute).

If you have "circular imports" in your own code, that's means you can create a third file or forth file to save your things.
First
find the "circle".
It's easy, cause you know where your circle is.
import mre

and
import EvFilter

Second
Find where to use those thing. In mre.py:
Class SubBox(QWidget):
...

and
Class TestWindow(QMainWindow):
...

and In EvFilter.py:
Class WindowEventFilter(CustomEventFilter):
...

and
Class SubBoxEventFilter(CustomEventFilter):
...

Third
Put those class into another file. In general, if one file import a file contains "main", we know that we should correct the file, or take main out.
One principle: "Don't import main in other file."
So we take out those things need to be imported in other file, into another file.
tsong.py (store TestSong and etc.)
from PySide6.QtCore import (Qt, QSize, QPoint, QRect,
                            QEvent, QObject,
                            Signal, SignalInstance, Slot,
                            )

from PySide6.QtGui import (QResizeEvent, QMoveEvent,
                           QFocusEvent, )

from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel,
                               QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, 
                               QMainWindow, QApplication,
                               QSizePolicy, QLayout, QLayoutItem
                               )
class TestSong(QWidget):

    # Create signals to relay info about meatball
    meatballCreated = Signal(QWidget, name="meatballCreated")
    meatballDestroyed = Signal(QWidget, name="meatballDestroyed")

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")

        # Init layout on widget
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        # Crate widgets
        label = QLabel("Label")
        meatball = TestSongButton("Meatball button")

        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(meatball)

        # connect clicked signal to relay into a meatballCreate signal, passing this widget
        # as a param
        meatball.clicked.connect(
            lambda checked: self.meatballCreated.emit(self))  
    
class TestSongButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__(text)

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: purple")
    
class TestSongMeatball(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, songWidget: TestSong, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Set reference to song widget
        self._songWidget = songWidget

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")

        # Create sizePolicy obj, init with horizontal and vertical preferences
        policy = QSizePolicy()
        policy.setHorizontalPolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
        policy.setVerticalPolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)

        # Set policy, min and max size of the widget.
        self.setSizePolicy(policy)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(70, 50))
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(160, 80))

        fPolicy = Qt.FocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setFocusPolicy(fPolicy)

        # Assign layout to widget
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        # Add demo label for clarity
        text = QLabel("Meatball Menu")
        layout.addWidget(text)

    @property
    def songWidget(self):
        return self._songWidget

    def findPos(self):
        p = self.parent()
        # First check that there is a song meatball created as a child of monitorObj (_widget)
        if p.findChild(TestSongMeatball):
            # find song item and store its position
            item_pos = self.songWidget.pos()

            # Type hint for Python intellisense purposes
            # find button within song item and store its position
            button: TestSongButton = self.songWidget.findChild(TestSongButton)
            button_pos = button.pos()

            # since item sits inside SubBox, the meatball will have the same geometry starting point (I think?)
            # So to find the button we need to add them
            x,y = item_pos.x(), item_pos.y()
            nx,ny, = button_pos.x(), button_pos.y()

            # Add co-ordinates to get button's top left corner
            meatball_pos = QPoint(x+nx,y+ny)
            
            # Move to new position, then allow QT to find correct size, using SizePolicy.
            self.move(meatball_pos)
            self.adjustSize()

        return

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(80,60)

subbox.py

from PySide6.QtCore import (Qt, QSize, QPoint, QRect,
                            QEvent, QObject,
                            Signal, SignalInstance, Slot,
                            )

from PySide6.QtGui import (QResizeEvent, QMoveEvent,
                           QFocusEvent, )

from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel,
                               QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, 
                               QMainWindow, QApplication,
                               QSizePolicy, QLayout, QLayoutItem
                               )

import EvFilter
from tsong import TestSongMeatball, TestSong

class SubBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")

        # Create and apply layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self) 

    @Slot()
    def addWid(self, item: TestSong):
        if self.findChild(TestSongMeatball):
            print("Meatball already present.")
            return
        
        # Create meatball widget
        meatball = TestSongMeatball(item, self)
        evFilter = EvFilter.MeatballEventFilter(meatball, item.meatballDestroyed)

        meatball.findPos()
        meatball.show()  # show meatball
        meatball.setFocus()

        return

    @Slot()
    def remWid(self, meatball: TestSongMeatball):
        meatball.deleteLater()
        meatball = None

        return

and we only need import those things in EvFilter.py and main.py:
EvFilter.py
from PySide6.QtCore import (QEvent, QObject,
                            Signal, SignalInstance, 
                            )

from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QWidget, )

# from mre import (TestSongMeatball, SubBox, )
from tsong import TestSongMeatball
from subbox import SubBox

... and we don't change any below.

mre.py
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import (Qt, QSize, QPoint, QRect,
                            QEvent, QObject,
                            Signal, SignalInstance, Slot,
                            )

from PySide6.QtGui import (QResizeEvent, QMoveEvent,
                           QFocusEvent, )

from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel,
                               QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, 
                               QMainWindow, QApplication,
                               QSizePolicy, QLayout, QLayoutItem
                               )

import EvFilter
from subbox import SubBox
from tsong import TestSong



class TestWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        window_widget = QWidget()
        window_layout = QVBoxLayout(window_widget)

        winFilter = EvFilter.WindowEventFilter(window_widget)

        fPolicy = Qt.FocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setFocusPolicy(fPolicy)

        #TODO: put this into a function
        # Give total layout a label
        window_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Window"))
        
        # Create sub-box
        sub = SubBox()

        # Install event filter to SubBox
        subFilter = EvFilter.SubBoxEventFilter(sub)

        test_widget = TestSong()

        sub.layout().addWidget(test_widget)
        
        window_layout.addWidget(sub)
        
        test_widget.meatballCreated.connect(
            lambda item: sub.addWid(item))
        
        test_widget.meatballDestroyed.connect(
            lambda meatball : sub.remWid(meatball))
        
        # set window as central
        self.setCentralWidget(window_widget)
        
def main():
    # Create app
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

IMPORTANT THING
a file contains "main" function only do main!
